# Confusion on how groups acts on objects

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-actions

im trying to learn group theory to understand particle physics and im currently reading: "A Simple Introduction to Particle Physics ,Part I - Foundations and the Standard Model". In the chapter called Group Actions he uses an example of three colorred eggs (ROY) and defines the actions:

1. Let e be doing nothing to the set, so e(ROY ) = (ROY ).
2. Let g1 be a cyclic permutation of the three, g1(ROY ) = (OY R)
3. Let g2 be a cyclic permutation in the other direction, g2(ROY ) = (Y RO)
4. Let g3 be swapping the first and second, g3(ROY ) = (ORY )
5. Let g4 be swapping the first and third, g4(ROY ) = (Y OR)
6. Let g5 be swapping the second and third, g5(ROY ) = (RY O)

which gives us this table:

$
\begin{array}{|c||c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline(G, \star) & e & g_{1} & g_{2} & g_{3} & g_{4} & g_{5} \\
\hline e & e & g_{1} & g_{2} & g_{3} & g_{4} & g_{5} \\
\hline g_{1} & g_{1} & g_{2} & e & g_{5} & g_{3} & g_{4} \\
\hline g_{2} & g_{2} & e & g_{1} & g_{4} & g_{5} & g_{3} \\
\hline g_{3} & g_{3} & g_{4} & g_{5} & e & g_{1} & g_{2} \\
\hline g_{4} & g_{4} & g_{5} & g_{3} & g_{2} & e & g_{1} \\
\hline g_{5} & g_{5} & g_{3} & g_{4} & g_{1} & g_{2} & e \\
\hline
\end{array}
$

Later in the paper he generalizes the three eggs by a set of objects $M= {m_0,m_1,m_2}$ and then building an algebra with these objects the orthonormal vectors are: $m_0 \rightarrow |m_0> $ and so on. During the example of the section on how $S_3$ acts on theses objects he writes:

$
g_{1}\left(c_{0}\left|m_{0}\right\rangle+c_{1}\left|m_{1}\right\rangle+c_{2}\left|m_{2}\right\rangle\right)=\left(c_{0}\left|g_{1} m_{0}\right\rangle+c_{1}\left|g_{1} m_{1}\right\rangle+c_{2}\left|g_{1} m_{2}\right\rangle\right) 
$
and from the multiplication table we can see that
$
g_1m_0=m_1 , g_1m_1=m_0,g_1m_2=m_2, \Rightarrow \left(c_{0}\left|g_{1} m_{0}\right\rangle+c_{1}\left|g_{1} m_{1}\right\rangle+c_{2}\left|g_{1} m_{2}\right\rangle\right)=\left(c_{0}\left|m_{1}\right\rangle+c_{1}\left| m_{0}\right\rangle+c_{2}\left|m_{2}\right\rangle\right) 
$

I have two questions about all of this. First of all im looking at the table and i don't understand how the last relations came to be. To my understanding $g_1m_1=m_2$. My second question is this: How are the eggs and the $m$ vectors related? What is the analogy here? Is $|m_1>$ the red egg for example? If so why aren't their positions swapped in the same way in how it swaps the eggs?

Comment: You're likely making an off-by-one error because the group labels start with $g_1$ but the vector labels start with $m_0$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... the group labels start with e which is the identity and then the second element is $g_1$, if thats what you mean.

Comment: $g_1$ swaps the first two elements of the set, which are $m_0$ and $m_1$ for the vectors. By comparison $g_1$ acts on the group by swapping $g_1$ and $g_2$. Notice that the labels switched but it's still just a transposition.

Comment: When $g_1$ acts on the eggs it moves every egg one place to the left, but when it acts on the m vectors it only swaps $m_0$ and $m_1$

Comment: Then you're right, and the text has not correctly described the group action. They probably made the same error I did.

Comment: Looks like a mistake to me, too. But what’s puzzling is the comment (from the version of the paper at https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.3328.pdf, assuming you are talking about Example 17) that says “from the multiplication table on page 19, we see that...” If the group is supposed to permute the $m_i$ in the same way it did the eggs (and Example 16 suggests that to me), it wouldn’t be the multiplication table that lets you evaluate the $g_i m_j$; it would be the definitions of the $g_i$ above the multiplication table. Not sure what’s going on at all.

Comment: That's what confuses me too

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm wrong but if I did it correctly I found that from the table we have:

$g_1=(132),\ g_2=(123),\ g_3=(23),\ g_4=(12),\ g_5=(13)$

Which has something problematic since then $g_1$ couldn't stabilize $m_2$.

Comment: what do you mean by stabilizing $m_2$ ?

Comment: I mean $g_1m_2=m_2$. If you consider the action of $S_3$ in three objects then only the transpositions can stabilize an object. But $g_1$ is a $3-$cycle